# Laravel, How to update user profile and check if phone number is duplicated

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using ajax to update user profile in the same page, I dont have any problem with this, as the user is logged in, then the controller check the user id from the Auth as in the code below, but in registration page its check if the phone number is duplicated but in update I dont know how to do this and also to ignore update for the current user if he didnt update his phone number!

Controller:

```
 public function update(Request $request)
  {
  $user_id=Auth::user()->id;
  User::where('id', $user_id)->update([
  'phone' => $request->phone,
  'fname' => $request->fname,
  'lname' => $request->lname
  ]);
   return Response::json(array(
   ));
  }
   }
```

Comment: its in the docs for the `unique` validation rule

Comment: do you have more information????

Comment: more information about what? the documentation in the Laravel docs for the Validation rule explains how to ignore records when using the `unique` rule https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-unique

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can actually validate data before you get to your controller. It's much safer, and you will have a cleaner code. First, create your custom request validation:

```
php artisan make:request UserRequest
```

This will create an empty `UserRequest` class, where you can validate your data:

```
class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    //Validate your data here
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'phone' => 'required|unique:users',
            'fname' => 'required',
            'lname' => 'required',
        ];
    }
    
    //Add custom message if validation fails
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'phone.required' => 'Phone is required.',
            'phone.unique' => 'Phone number should be unique.',
            'fname.unique' => 'First name is required.',
            'lname.required' => 'Last name is required.',
        ];
    }
}
```

All you have to do now, is import this custom validation inside your controller:

```
public function update(UserRequest $request)
  {
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    User::where('id', $user_id)->update([
      'phone' => $request->phone,
      'fname' => $request->fname,
      'lname' => $request->lname
    ]);

    return;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

There has one issue. That is
**'phone' => 'unique:App\User,phone,' . $user->phone,**
line.

## **Your Code:**

You need to validate the request before saving to database

```
public function update(Request $request)
  {
    $user = Auth::user();

    $request->validate([
      // unique:table,column,except,idColumn
      'phone' => 'unique:App\User,phone,' . **$user->phone**,
    ]);

    $user_id=Auth::user()->id;
    
    User::where('id', $user_id)->update([
      'phone' => $request->phone,
      'fname' => $request->fname,
      'lname' => $request->lname
    ]);
    
    return;
  }
I hope it helps you.
```

**This will make an issue**. You should use **$this->phone**.

public function update(Request $request)
{
$user = Auth::user();

```
$request->validate([
  // unique:table,column,except,idColumn
  'phone' => 'unique:App\User,phone,' . $this->phone,
]);

$user_id=Auth::user()->id;

User::where('id', $user_id)->update([
  'phone' => $request->phone,
  'fname' => $request->fname,
  'lname' => $request->lname
]);

return;
```

}

Try this one.